# Using Ignite for Hibernate 2nd level cache with S3 discovery, changes are not progagated

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, amazon-s3

We have deployed a cluster to AWS configured to use Ignite as a hibernate 2nd level cache, and we're using S3 discovery. On startup we can see the nodes do connect to each other correctly.

However, when a hibernate entity is updated on one server, the change is not propagated through the cluster so other servers continue to have the old value.

Here is a snippet of our ignite config..
```

```
<!-- Basic configuration for transactional cache. -->
<bean id="transactional-cache" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration" abstract="true">
    <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED"/>
    <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
    <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_ASYNC"/>
    <property name="backups" value="0"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration" >
    <property name="discoverySpi" ref="discoverySpi"/>
    <property name="gridName" value="hibernate-grid"/>
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean parent="transactional-cache">
                <property name="name" value="hibernate.io.milton.vfs.db.Auditable"/>
            </bean>
```

```

The exact same application code, when configured with hazelcast 2nd level cache, does work.

I'm sure there's just something wrong with our config. Can anyone suggest a pointer?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you hit a known issue with binary format which is used as the default one in Ignite. See the warning callout here for details: https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/hibernate-l2-cache#l2-cache-configuration

Switching to `OptimizedMarshaller` should fix the issue.

Comment: Cheers, will give that a go.